# matplotbib figure horization axis label automatically alignment or rescale

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was trying to plot a time series data figure using matplotbib, the problem is that there are too many observations, therefore the labels have overlap and don't fit well within a sized figure.

I am thinking of three solutions, one is to shrink the label size of observations, one is to change the text into vertical order or skewed manner, last is only to specify the first and last a few observations with dots between them. The code is to demonstrate my point.

I wonder anyone can help? Thanks

```
from datetime import date
import numpy as np
from pandas import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100
data = np.array(np.random.randn(N))
time_index = date_range(date.today(), periods = len(data))
plt.plot(time_index, data)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your simple plot, you could do

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90).
```

Alternatively, you could specify what ticks you wanted to display with

```
plt.xticks(<certain range of values>)
plt.xticklabels(<labels for those values>)
```

Edit:

Personally, I would change to the object-oriented way of pyplot.

```
f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(<stuff>)
ax.tick_params(axis='x', labelsize='8')

plt.setp( ax.xaxis.get_majorticklabels(), rotation=90 )
# OR
xlabels = ax.get_xticklabels()
for label in xlabels:
    label.set_rotation(90)

plt.show()
```

Comment: thanks, how to shrink the character size of those labels also?